# Conditionally run tests at runtime using Nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch to run my end to end tests but I would like to conditionally run certain tests based on some global settings at runtime.

```
// globals.js
module.exports = {
    FLAG: true
};

// test.js
describe('Something', () => {
  it('should do something', client => {
      if (client.globals.FLAG) {
          expect(1).to.equal(1);
      }
  });
});
```

The above works fine, but I want to silent the whole test and conditionally include the `it` e.g:

```
// test.js
describe('Something', () => {
  // client does not exist out here so it does not work.
  if (client.globals.FLAG) {
      it('should do something', client => {
          expect(1).to.equal(1);
      });
  }
});
```

I am aware I can skip tests by defining them in the `nightwatch.js` and excluding files etc etc but thats not the approach I can use in this implementation. Another solution might be to use tags but I'm not sure this is possible using Mocha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the flag in the second example by importing your module `globals.js`:

```js
// test.js

const globals = require('../globals.js');

describe('Something', () => {

  if (globals.FLAG) {
      it('should do something', client => {
          expect(1).to.equal(1);
      });
  }
});
```

you could also create a function to ignore the test when the condition is met:

```js
// test.js

const FLAG = require('../globals.js').FLAG;
const not = function(v){ return {it: v ? function(){}: it} };

describe('Something', () => {

  not(FLAG).it('should do something', client => {
      expect(1).to.equal(1);
  });

});
```

Comment: This pretty much sums up the way I did it, with a custom syntax `when.SOMETHING.it`.